# IE Restrict JavaScript third party domain access other than *.currentwebsite.com

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

It is possible to disable JS at all.

It is possible to disable JS on certain domains by adding them to Restricted Zone for example.

I wonder if it is possible to block/restrict third party domain access other than *.currentwebsite.com for enabled JS in IE.

This could be somehow useful in ad blocking as well as security.

Or am I supposed to write an add-on myself?

Answer (score 1):

I don t know is it possible or not but it is definitely a bad idea as CDNs are highly popular these days and most of the page use these for CSS and JS file as well as image file.

To block ads you can also use hosts file (under system32\drivers\etc folder) if you have the list of the URLs (I am pretty sure you can find a list at the internet) just redirect them some fake address like localhost or a server response nothing.

Comment: So do I. Programms like AdMuncher block via those lists. On some reasons this is not an option for me. It is too aggressive plus it adds some own JavaScript on each page to prevent strange behaviour requests. Yeah, you said 'popular'. This is what I am trying to escape. A JS toggle-block button could be very helpful. Like 'Toggle Flash'. More smooth way could be alowing JS on current domain only.